# How to ensure that POD is deleted using ansible?

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

I am trying to validate that the pod is deleted.

```
- name: Verify whether the POD is deleted
  command: "{{ local_kubectl }} get pod {{ pod_name}}"
```

but the task is failing as the command displays error as below

> 'Error from server (NotFound): pods   ....'

But this is expected when i am checking for deletion of pod.

How to pass this task when it returns an error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just directly specify this using the [k8s module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/k8s_module.html#k8s-module)

```
- name: Delete the POD
  k8s:
    api_version: v1
    kind: Pod
    namespace: "{{ k8s_namespace }}"
    name: "{{ pod_name }}"
    state: absent
```

Another path is to [redefine "failure"](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#controlling-what-defines-failure) to check for the expected result string.

```
- name: Verify whether the POD is deleted
  command: "{{ local_kubectl }} get pod {{ pod_name}}"
  register: verify
  failed_when: "'NotFound' not in verify.stderr"
```

Comment: Can I use a regex with k8s as well as to remove all Pods that match an expression?

Answer (score 1):

Try [k8s_facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/k8s_facts_module.html#k8s-facts-describe-kubernetes-k8s-objects)

```
- k8s_facts:
    kind: Pod
    name: "{{ pod_name}}"
  register: result
- debug:
    var: result
```

(not tested)

Answer (score 1):

Late response. Hope it is helpful to someone.
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/kubernetes/core/k8s_module.html

```
- name: Delete pod
  kubernetes.core.k8s:
    state: absent
    kind: Pod
    name: "{{pod_name}}"
    namespace: "{{test_ns}}"
    kubeconfig: "{{ config }}"
    wait: true
    wait_condition:
      status: False #wait for status to be false
    wait_sleep: 2  #check every 2 secs
```